# Find the largest value in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, groovy, integer

I have a 2D array with every element that is a string, I need to convert the strings that contain numbers into integers.

```
String[][] weatherData = [["London", "23", "11", "10.1"],["Tokyo","21", "9", "11"], ["Cape Town", "31", "12", "21"]]
```

The first element of each array is the city name, the second is the highest temperature, the third is the lowest temperature and the fourth is the rainfall.

I need to convert all the number values to integers and then search the second element (highest temperature) of each array to find the highest temperature of the whole weatherData array and display that temperature.

If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: `weatherData.max { it[1].toInteger() }[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have int values in a string array.
But you can do a loop who compare every value ( string.toInteger() ) and return the highest.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the raw Strings arrays into object instances with proper data types (integers and floats).

From there you can do things more easily with the data, like find the city with the highest temperature. One way to do this is to sort the list of objects by high temperature and then return the first element of the list,.

```
class Record {
    String name; int high, low; double rainfall
    Record(name, high, low, rainfall) {
        this.name = name
        this.high = high.toInteger()
        this.low = low.toInteger()
        this.rainfall = Double.valueOf(rainfall)
    }
}

String[][] weatherData = [["London", "23", "11", "10.1"],["Tokyo","21", "9", "11"], ["Cape Town", "31", "12", "21"]]

def data = weatherData.collect { new Record(*it) }
def hottest = data.sort({ r1, r2 -> r2.high <=> r1.high}).first()
assert hottest.name == 'Cape Town'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this simple one?

```
String[][] weatherData = [["London", "23", "11", "10.1"],["Tokyo","21", "9", "11"], ["Cape Town", "31", "12", "21"]]
println weatherData.collect{ it[1] as Integer}.max()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Use this code to convert to integer and after that loop a bout the biggest temperature

```
// A program to demonstrate the use of stringstream
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "12345";

    // object from the class stringstream
    stringstream geek(s);

    // The object has the value 12345 and stream
    // it to the integer x
    int x = 0;
    geek >> x;

    // Now the variable x holds the value 12345
    cout << "Value of x : " << x;

   return 0;
}
```

[More Methods to Convert Click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/)